# Smallest touch point that can be accurately detected on a smartphone screen?

Tags: touch, smartphone, touchscreen

What is the smallest touch point that can be accurately detected on a typical Androud or iOS smartphone screen? Or (if you could reframe this question in a different way), what is narrowest tip that a smartphone stylus could have?

**UPDATE**

So I've done some Googling of touchscreen suppliers and the only possibly relevant spec I could find was touchpoint density, expressed as touchpoints/unit area. However, the numbers are absurdly high, something on the order of 100k/sq.inch. This would seem to imply that smartphone screens can detect touches that are as small as 10^-6 sq. inches, or touches that are thinner than a hair. Or my understanding of the unit of touchpoint density is flawed.

http://kingtouch.en.made-in-china.com/product/DqOQNaVjferi/China-22-Surface-Capacitive-Touch-Screen-KTT-CA22K-.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It varies from smartphone to smartphone, obviously. There are many different kinds of touchscreen (CCD, resistive, etc.) and each of them have their own general precision range. Here's a good PDF for you: [(though I don't know who it's by).](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.8316&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=t41NT9aFGMOegwfspeivAg&usg=AFQjCNHIZ-nGRuaqjS0J-wJT3cT_pmNivA&sig2=hW3CK0OF1wajVSVmZKs9yg)

The main problem is that this question has too general of an answer. There is no set value, and there is no scale for touchscreen precision (that I'm aware of).

Comment: Link is broken. Could you please post the actual link and not the Google search result link?

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.8316&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: And touchpoint density, though affecting touchscreen accuracy, isn't necessarily the determining factor.

Comment: Are the two completely independent of each other?

Comment: Not *completely* independent. They do affect each other, but it is not, by any means, the ONLY factor. There are many different kinds of touchscreens, and, to some extent, the operating system itself also places a chokehold on the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the touch sensor is 1-for-1 with the display (I have no idea if it is), just ask the API:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html